# OpenCover C# Branch Coverage says there should be a branch on throw new Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, opencover

I'm parsing a date and throwing an exception. Aside from verifying an invalid date format throws an exception, I'm not sure what other branch to hit.

I did try Exception vs ArgumentException, both had the same result.

[image]

[image]

I am pretty new to unit test branch coverage, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: that means you need a Test that will Assert if that exception is thrown by passing invalid data to it.

Comment: I think I have that test. I added it for reference. It says 1 out of 2 branches are covered. I'm just not sure what the 2nd branch could be.

Comment: how about a valid date time passed? That is another branch of the same thing

Comment: There shouldn't be any branching in that `throw` statement, unless there's something funky going on with either `request` or `AppTime`.

Comment: Yep, I have a couple of those too. You can see from the picture, the if block has 3 hits, but the throw statement just has one hit. The other two tests have valid dates and test other parts of the method.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes thats why I'm confused. I'm not sure how there can be branches here. The request is an object with only fields. ApptTime is just a string with a getter and setter. Super standard.

Comment: Could it be that you're running in Release mode and it's confused about where the branches really are due to an optimisation somewhere?

Comment: Thats a pretty good thought! I think it had to do with async code, but that could be a viable alternative

Answer (score 0):

So the issue turns out to be with async code. Here's where I got the info:

https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/657

Basically, the compiler generates some extra code in an async method, and OpenCover looks at the compiled code. I was not able to figure out an optimal solution.

In this case, I was able to return the Task instead of awaiting it in this service. That was removed the shadow branch from the code coverage.

In another case, I just had to add another null check or two to get above code coverage requirements.